# Google Cloud SQL Proxy could not find cloud SQL instance

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform

I want to connect google cloud SQL with local MYSQL client, and finnally connect to R. I am following this tutorial.https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/03/google-cloud-platform-for-data-scientists-using-r-with-google-cloud-sql-for-mysql

I have created SQL instance on the cloud. I used SDK connected to google cloud. When I run cloud_sql_proxy.exe, it gets me the following error.

```
C:\Users\mxia020\Downloads\google cloud SQL>cloud_sql_proxy.exe
2018/05/02 12:10:59 Using gcloud's active project: fsadm-201508
2018/05/02 12:11:00 Error listing instances in fsadm-201508: Get 
https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/fsadm-201508/instances? 
alt=json: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
Response: {
"error" : "invalid_grant",
"error_description" : "Invalid JWT Signature."
}
2018/05/02 12:11:00 no Cloud SQL Instances found in these projects: [fsadm- 
201508]
```

Comment: The error message seems to be saying that your Java web user token is bad, or wasn't recognized properly.

Comment: Try to check this post [https://thornelabs.net/2016/11/26/resolve-google-cloud-api-oauth2-cannot-fetch-token-invalid-grant-error.html ] that shows how to solve a similar issue and let us know if the solution offered helped you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure that instance you try to connect located in proper project
You can use fully qualified name

```
cloud_sql_proxy -instances=myprojectname:us-central1:instanceid=tcp:3306
```

You may also try to regenerate credentials

```
gcloud auth login
```

Comment: I mistakenly thought brackets should be around connection name based on the tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/quickstart
Looks like I need more coffee.. Thank you!